# Will remote shutter releases stop and start video?

Tags: video

I'm trying to figure out how I can remotely stop and start video from my Canon Rebel t3i.  Is this possible at all?

I know there are shutter releases that will snap off pictures, but will the same work when in video mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What time of remote shutter release?

Comment: It depends on the camera in question and possibly on the abilities of the remote device, since there are several of those too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about physical trigger devices, so not sure if starting/stopping a video is possible with those.

However, you can use a "software" trigger that is included in the modified [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) firmware that is available for free for several Canon cameras (including the 550D).

After you install the ML firmware on an SD card you will have access to many video recording enhancements, so it might be helpful in general.
According to the manual you can trigger the start/stop of a video (or take a photo) by using the [LCD sensor or the built-in microphone](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#lcdsensor_remote).
From experience I know that the audio trigger is more reliable than the LCD sensor, but it requires that you set the trigger volume threshold according to the sounds in the environment.

[Here's](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26695/9161) more information on the risks of using the custom firmware, and [here's](http://www.magiclantern.fm/install.html) 
the Magic Lantern installation guide.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of remote you are using. Pushing the button on a wired remote such as the RS60-E3, the RS80-N3, or any of their many generic equivalents will function *exactly* the same as pushing the button on the camera's built in shutter release button. This applies to both half and full presses of the button. You can use the wired remote in any exposure mode, focus mode, drive mode, etc. **It is exactly the same as if you were pressing the camera's shutter button.**

If you are using a wireless remote such as the Canon RC-6 with a camera with a compatible infrared receiver, you are limited to shooting only in "Self Timer" mode.